# Swift 2 Official guide/documentation Link?

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm learning Swift from Stanford IOS course. Unfortunately it isn't updated to Swift 3. I've heard that there haven't been major changes in language itself but some syntax and methods have changed (not sure though).

According to reading assignments I have to follow the Official [Apple Docs Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) but it has Swift 3 covered only. I can't find any option in the site to show me the old guide for Swift 2.
Besides experimenting everything in Xcode is there an official documentation for Swift 2 ? I googled a lot but couldn't find an official one.

** *EDIT* **

If my question doesn't seem helpful for future readers, then at least can someone point me to an official Change log ?
For example
`func abc()` changed to `func xyz()` in Swift 3..

Comment: You'll learn more reading the up-to-date [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) book for Swift 3 than spending time learning old, out-of-date version of Swift online.

Comment: @rmaddy So what are you suggesting that I ditch the all great Paul Hegarty's Stanford IOS course  ?

Comment: Generally Xcode will tell you when you are using old syntax and suggest the appropriate change.  Just try it

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm using xcode 7.3, I also have to maintain a project made in Swift 2, thats what I'm trying to explain..

Comment: Use Xcode 8.2 and set legacy swift mode for older projects.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much every syntax change is covered by Xcode or at least function names are similar. I personally haven't experienced any difficulties with going through Swift 2 CS193p, when Swift 3 was already out. And as far as I know, some of the 2017 lectures are already published over at iTunes.